# Is this json formatted correctly?

Tags: json

I'm am not sure that this json is formatted correctly can someone tell me what is wrong with the formatting?

```
{"response": 1,
"data": { "events": [
{

"placeTitle":"Griffwood Dr",
"placeAddress": "Canonsburg, ,  ",
"downCount": "0",
"time": "2015-01-01 06:47:28 UTC",
"nameOfHost": "Tyler Rice",
"event_id": "21",

"userresponse": "0",
"people_down": []
},

]

}}
```

Comment: tried http://jsonlint.com/ ?

Comment: There's an extra comma quite at the end that shouldn't be there.

Comment: I like to use this site for testing and debugging JSON: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the comma if you are not going to have another object:

```
{"response": 1,
"data": { "events": [
{

"placeTitle":"Griffwood Dr",
"placeAddress": "Canonsburg, ,  ",
"downCount": "0",
"time": "2015-01-01 06:47:28 UTC",
"nameOfHost": "Tyler Rice",
"event_id": "21",

"userresponse": "0",
"people_down": []
}

]

}}
```

For future, you can use a JSON parser such as [this one.](http://json.parser.online.fr/)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the extra comma after the object within the array.  Since there is only one object in the array there is no need to use the comma delimiter, which would normally separate objects.

```
{
    "placeTitle":"Griffwood Dr",
    "placeAddress": "Canonsburg, ,  ",
    "downCount": "0",
    "time": "2015-01-01 06:47:28 UTC",
    "nameOfHost": "Tyler Rice",
    "event_id": "21", 
    "userresponse": "0",
    "people_down": []
}, //remove this comma
```